# How to prove equality commutes in Idris?

Tags: idris

Trying to prove the following assertion:

```hs
equalityCommutesNat : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> n = m -> m = n
```

I found `plusCommutes` in the libraries but nothing for equality.

Comment: i'm pretty new to this stuff, but isn't this the definition of `=`? what are you trying to do with `equalityCommutesNat`?

Comment: It’s purely a self set task, I’m just starting with small simple properties to build up my understanding of theorem proving as it’s currently highly unintuitive for me. I’m assuming there’s a proof of this that goes conceptually like so: n = m is effectively equivalent to x = x for some x that n = x, m = x. Therefore m = x = n.

Comment: One thing in the library you might find useful for this is `sym`. Maybe you were looking through the proofs that are specific to `Nat`, but this works for any equality: `sym : a = b -> b = a`

Comment: Thanks @EdwinBrady - I tried to prove it using `sym` but it hasn't worked for me yet in idris2: `equalityCommutes _ _ p = rewrite sym in p`.

Comment: You can only rewrite with equalities, and `sym` is a function from one equality to another, so you need to apply it to `p`. After that you already have your answer and there's no need to rewrite.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderGryzlov, I tried this also but it didn't work: `equalityCommutes _ _ = sym`. (can't unify `(0 _ : ?x = ?y) -> ?y = ?x and _ = _ -> _ = _`).

Comment: Oh but `equalityCommutes n m p = sym p` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only inhabitant of `=` is `Refl : (a = a)`, so if you pattern match, you'll get evidence that `n` is `m`.

Which means you can then use `Refl`, since Idris's pattern matching now knows they're the same:

```
equalityCommutesNat : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> n = m -> m = n
equalityCommutesNat _ _ Refl = Refl
```

And you can play around with this in the REPL:

```
> equalityCommutesNat 1 1 Refl
Refl : 1 = 1
```